# sql server stored proc dynamic select

Tags: sql-server

I have a  stored proc in the following format

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[test proc] 
@identifier varchar(20),
@issuerName varchar(max),
@max_records  int=1000
AS
BEGIN
declare @select nvarchar(30)

SELECT @identifier as '@identifier'
    , (
        SELECT 
        MoodysOrgID as '@MoodysOrgID'
        ,ReportDate as '@ReportDate'
        ,m.UpdateTime as '@UpdateTime'
        ,m.FileCreationDate as '@FileCreationDate'
        from mfm_financial_ratios m
        inner join mfm_financial_ratios_coa c on c.AcctNo = m.AcctNo
        where ReportDate in (select distinct top (@max_records) reportdate from mfm_financial_ratios where MoodysOrgID = m.MoodysOrgID) 
        and m.MoodysOrgID=(select top 1 IssuerID_Moodys as id from loans where LIN=@identifier or LoanXID=@identifier
                           and ParentName_Moodys=@issuerName and IssuerID_Moodys is not null)
        order by ReportDate desc
        FOR XML PATH('FinRatios'), TYPE
    )
    FOR XML PATH('FinRatiosHistory')

END
```

but i would like to make by query execute as dynamic sql

and my stored proc looks like

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[test proc] 
    @identifier varchar(20),
    @issuerName varchar(max),
    @max_records  int=1000
    AS
    BEGIN
    declare @select nvarchar(30)

set    @select = N'SELECT @identifier as '@identifier'
        , (
            SELECT 
            MoodysOrgID as '@MoodysOrgID'
            ,ReportDate as '@ReportDate'
            ,m.UpdateTime as '@UpdateTime'
            ,m.FileCreationDate as '@FileCreationDate'
            from mfm_financial_ratios m
            inner join mfm_financial_ratios_coa c on c.AcctNo = m.AcctNo
            where ReportDate in (select distinct top (@max_records) reportdate from mfm_financial_ratios where MoodysOrgID = m.MoodysOrgID) 
            and m.MoodysOrgID=(select top 1 IssuerID_Moodys as id from loans where LIN=@identifier or LoanXID=@identifier
                               and ParentName_Moodys=@issuerName and IssuerID_Moodys is not null)
            order by ReportDate desc
            FOR XML PATH('FinRatios'), TYPE
        )
        FOR XML PATH('FinRatiosHistory')'
exec @select

    END
```

The following stored proc gives issues because of the comma used in it .Can someone let me know what you be the correct way of doing it

Comment: You have two problems... first, you need to escape the quotes in your dynamic query by changing each single quote (`'`) to double single quotes (`''`').  Next problem, the variables within your dynamic sql are out of scope and would need to be passed in use `sp_ExecuteSQL`.  However, I see no reason why you would *want* this to by dynamic SQL.  May I ask why you're trying to do this?

Comment: i would be breaking query into multiple part for different reason  which i am not showcasing in my sample stored proc

Answer (score 0):

The problem are not the commas. You mostly have two problems: one, you're not escaping the quotes correctly. And two, you're not concatenating your variables correctly. Here's an example of both:

For concatenating variables: In your first select line, you cannot do this:

```
SELECT @identifier as '@identifier'
```

because sql does not know what to do with @identifier that way. You should concatenate the variable this way:

```
SELECT @identifier as ' + @identifier + '.. everything else goes here
```

Also, when you will have to concatenate max_records, since it's an int variable you should cast it to varchar first, like this:

```
select distinct top (' + cast(@max_records as varchar(10) + ')  ....
```

**Whenever you're using a variable in the middle of the string (such as @max_records) you HAVE to concatenate it in order for SQL to know it's a variable and not just a string**. You didn't do it with max_records, @issuerName, etc.

For escaping quotes: You need to escape your single quotes when you don't want your select string to unexpectedly end. For example here:

```
FOR XML PATH('FinRatiosHistory')'
```

You should escape them with double quotes (google escaping single quotes sql if you don't get it)

```
FOR XML PATH(''FinRatiosHistory'')'
```